# CocoaPods arm64 issue

Tags: ios7, xcode5, cocoapods, arm64

When using Podfile for developing iOS 7 app with Xcode5, we always got this issue.

After some searching, seems like no final resolve from CocoaPods ?  Maybe resolved at this moment when you see this.

How to resolve such issues right now ?

The issue was:
Pods was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods.a' because its architectures 'armv7 armv7s' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s arm64'

Comment: What is the problem? You can manually choose architectures in Pods project.

Answer (score 200):

1. Select the `Pods` project
2. Change `Build Active Architecture Only` from `Yes` to `No`.

That worked for me.

Note:
[CocoaPods Troubleshooting Guide](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html#running-into-build-failures-after-migrating-to-xcode--and-cocoapods-) recommends matching the Debug setting in your Xcode project, rather than changing the Pod's `Build Active Architecture Only`. As long as they match it seems to fix the problem.

[image]

Comment: The guide recommends that you set your project's Build Active Architecture Only from NO to YES for Debug. That will match the CocoaPods setting. 

I'm guessing that's to make it build faster on Debug builds. I'm not sure why they force it.

http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/troubleshooting.html#running-into-build-failures-after-migrating-to-xcode--and-cocoapods-

Comment: Found a nice way to automate this. Just add a [snippet](https://gist.github.com/funroll/7faf18b4972d72cd284e) to the end of your Podfile.

Comment: dont mess with the active archiecture on the pods... I ended up getting 30 or so build errors around different pods when I did that. I instead matched my project's debug active architecture to the pods project.

Comment: I noticed that after I set to Yes, I cleaned and built my project. Then went back and reset it to No and my project still builds correctly.

Comment: For those like me new to ios dev and looking for the build settings : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/Articles/EditingBuildSettings.html

Answer (score 26):

First, try updating cocoapods in your terminal: `gem update cocoapods`

If it doesn't work after that, go into your workspace, click on the Pod project, select all Pod targets and set `Architectures` to `(armv7 armv7s arm64)`.

Still nothing? Try switching it all back to `(armv7 armv7s)`.

[image: xcode screenshot]

Comment: I had similar problems and I upgraded from 0.25.0 to 0.26.2 and that resolved the issue.

Comment: This worked like a charm with some of the issues I was having with individual pods.

Comment: 'gem update cocoapods' worked for me. Been trying to fix a problem for hours... Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I had similar issues on `XCode 6.1` where`pod install` would frequently re-introduce linking errors. Adding `$(OTHER_LDFLAGS)` to the my target's `"Other Linker Flags"` got me through this. Please see if this helps.

Comment: You're right man! Thanks a lot for helping. This is the exact error if you're in Xcode 6.1 and you ran pod install! Thanks a lot man.

Comment: Thanks man, that solved my problem too. As a matter of fact `pod install` did warn me about this, but the ignorant that I am ignored it!

Answer (score 4):

Just to chip in to the "possible solutions"-pool and because a lot of people with CocoaPods issues are finding this page from Google:

I tried pretty much all suggested solutions, but the thing that did it for me was: In the Pods project in your workspace, go to `Build Settings` -> `Base-SDK`. This should be stated in bold. Press backspace to set it to default and set it back to your preferences again (in my case `Latest iOS(iOSx.x)`).

This oddly solved all my invalid architecture errors. Might help others.

Comment: Didn't expect the last solution in the list to work ... but it did. Thanks a lot!