# iOS: MWPhotoBrowser build on device

Tags: ios, build, mwphotobrowser

Today I have added to my project `MWPhotoBrowser` using `cocoapods` source control.

Tests in emulator where correct but when I start to test app on devices (ipode touch 5gen and iphone 4s) I got few issues:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/user/Pods/build/Debug-iphoneos'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7s:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MWPhotoBrowser", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in KYMUFinalPageTVC.o
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MWPhoto", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in KYMUFinalPageTVC.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: are you sure you added all the classes to your build target ?

Comment: I thought that cocoapods automatically add all needed classes. But where can I check that all classes where added?

Comment: I add the same issue, any solution?

Comment: At the moment I refused to use cocoapods in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get this error with MWPhotoBrowser and you're in Xcode 6.1, then do this,

Go to your project -> Build Settings, and search for "Other Linked Flags" and add $(OTHER_LDFLAGS) to it.

Source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26721045/1032179