# Realm doesn't support armv7s

Tags: ios, realm

I got this error when trying to build via command line:

```
ld: file is universal (4 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/../Framework/Realm.framework/Realm file '/Users/../Framework/Realm.framework/Realm' for architecture armv7s
```

Here is the command line code:

```
xcodebuild -scheme $SCHEME ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO ARCHS="armv7 armv7s x86_64" PROVISIONING_PROFILE=$provi PRODUCT_NAME=$AP_NAME ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_APPICON_NAME=$AppIcon archive -archivePath ../build/$AP_NAME.xcarchive
```

I am using version 0.87.

**Update**

Realm actually doesn't support armv7s. (In my case, Realm version 0.87).

```
lipo Realm -info
Architectures in the fat file: Realm are: i386 x86_64 armv7 arm64
```

Please fix this issues Realm team!!!

Comment: Most likely not.  armv7s was pulled from the list of standard architectures recently.

Comment: Yes, I think so. But the error gives me that Realm doesn't support. Can you please check it?

Comment: How should I check it?  I don'T work for Realm...

The real question is why do you need armv7s?  There is only 1 device that I know of that uses it, and it can also run armv7.

Comment: We need support any phone that runs iOS 8. And from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517822/do-i-need-to-add-armv6-support-when-limiting-apps-to-ios-4-0 , we need armv7s.

Comment: Any armv7s can run armv7 code...so you don't technically need it.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25398898/1155387) is relevant to the discussion.

Comment: So I only need support armv7 and arm64, don't I?

Answer (score 3):

As borrrden has indicated in his comments to the question, armv7s isn't actually required to run on any device (iPhone 5, iPhone 5c & iPad 4 were the first devices to support it, but can also run armv7 binaries) and [the armv7 instruction set only has minor differences compared to armv7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24040497/xcode-6-standard-architectures-exclude-armv7s/25398898#25398898) which don't justify the increase in file size.

If you require specific armv7s support, feel free to build Realm from source. [The cocoa binding is entirely open-source](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa). You can also do this very easily using CocoaPods ([see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19422362/373262)).